Proof of the existence of the haar measure for compact group
I'm following these notes.
In the proof of the Theorem 4 (page 3) there is an inequality that i am not able to verify.

Let $G$ a compact group and $V$ an open neighbourhood of the identity.
$A$ is called a $V$-blocking set if $A \cap gVh \neq \emptyset$ for
all $g,h \in G$.
For any multi-set $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ we define the positive linear
functional $L_A:C(G)\to \mathbb{R}$ by $L_A := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n f(a_i)$.
Let $W \subseteq V$ neighbourhoods of the identity. We choose $A$ a
$W$-blocking set and $B$  a $V$-blocking set (Note that
the blocking sets are finite and of minimum cardinality). Let $C=AB$, then
$$|L_Af-L_Cf|\leq \frac{1}{|B|}\sum_{b \in B}|L_Af-L_{Ab}f|.$$

The above inequality is obviously true if $|C|=|A||B|$, but in general this is not verified. So ot it is the result of  simple algebraic manipulations or maybe we can traslate the blocking sets to have $|C|=|A||B|$ (a traslation of a blocking set is a blocking set and changing the blocking set is not a big deal)

Here it seems $C$ is intended to be defined not as a set but as a multiset, so $C=AB$ means that the products are counted with multiplicity (i.e. if there are multiple pairs $(a,b)\in A\times B$ with the same product, you get that many copies of the element in $C$).  This makes $|C|=|A||B|$ always true.
